# Multiple table rows as a backbone.js view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

So I have a grid of data, and each item in the grid has an associated model and view. I need to render each item as **two** table rows to achieve the desired UI. (No, it wasn't my design...)

First attempt: in the view's `render()` method, just render two rows and add them to `this.el`. Then I append each view to the table, and discover that every pair of rows has been wrapped in a `<div>`. Invalid HTML and the layout is all wrong.

Ok, second attempt: render two rows in the view again, but instead of appending the entire view to the table, I just append the child rows by using `tableItemView.$("tr")`. Hooray, it works! But hold on ... the row events have now stopped firing. I discover this is because backbone uses `jQuery.delegate`, so all the events were delegated to the original `el` which is no longer part of the table.

I love backbone's clean architecture but struggle to find a nice solution to this. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: I don't have access to it right now, but can post some tomorrow if it would help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Setting

```
tagName: 'tbody'
```

should allow you to group the related tr tags together without breaking the table and still allow this.el to work.

Comment: OK - but I'd then need to append several of these `tbody` elements to the same table. That doesn't sound quite right.

Comment: Actually, it looks like multiple `tbody`s are allowed in tables: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3 - I did not know that.

Answer (score 1):

In your view object, what is your tagName property set to?

From the docs:

```
this.el is created from the view's tagName, className, and id properties, 
if specified. If not, el is an empty div
```

You probably want to set

```
tagName: 'tr'
```

And then in render():

```
$(this.el).html("<td>content for row one</td>").append("<tr><td>content for row two</td></tr>");
```

That may not work exactly, but you get the idea.

Comment: Won't that `append()` add the second row inside the first row? Is that what you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to simply create 2 small views that each reference the same model, one for each row.

Depending on how integrated the 2 rows need to be (perhaps moved/sorted as a unit), you could have a 'controller'-like view that creates the subview and orchestrates their behavior.