# How to show CompositeView with multiple children view in Backbone Marionette

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

### The Starting Problem

I have a CompositeView (a table) for which each model in the collection is represented as two table rows, with a template like:

```
<tr class="row-parent">
    <td>parent info here</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-child">
    <td>child info here</td>
</tr>
```

With an ItemView like this:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: ItemTmpl
});
```

Even though they are named 'parent' and 'child', they are actually peer members of the same model.  If I don't specify a tagName, Backbone will wrap each view in a `<div>` which is both invalid HTML and also breaks the layout.

### The First Attempt at a Solution

So I figured, why not remove the outer `<tr>` tags and let Backbone add them in.  So I updated my template to be like:

```
    <td>parent info here</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row-child">
    <td>child info here</td>
```

And updated the view to:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: ItemTmpl,
    tagName: 'tr',
    className: 'row-parent'
});
```

I was hoping that an outer tag would combine with the inner tag fragments, but Marionette didn't like that.  It only showed the row-child.  So I'm not sure where to go from here.  I'm considering two strategies but haven't gone into much details yet.

### Moving Forward: Plan A

Override whatever part of Backbone creates the extra div to not create it, or override the part of Marionette which appends the view to remove the div just before appending.

### Moving Forward: Plan B

Create a new type of view called CompositeMultiView which, naturally, would extend off CompositeView and allow you two specify a second ItemView, or maybe just an array of views, all of which would be rendered for each model given.  This plan seems like a lot more work but less hacked.

---

Does anyone have any better suggestions, workarounds or concrete pointers as to how I would go about implementing either of the two above plans?

Here is a mockup of what the table should look like:
[image]

Comment: On first glance I would definitely go with Plan B. Also, could you give a rough example of what sort of data structure you're dealing with? I want to confirm that a `CompositeView` is best here.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't think the data structure is particularly unusual or complex.  It's simply an array of models.  I think a CompositeView is appropriate because I want to display the models (leaf) in a table (branch) and this is pretty much what CompositeView was invented for.

The only unusual part is that there is too much data to be represented in one table row, so I wanted to show it as two table rows.

Comment: Hear me out, @T Nguyen. If it's a flat array of models and shown across two rows, I see no need for the `CompositeView`. You could just have an ItemView with a template that spreads the data across two table rows. `CompositeView` makes more sense if you were listing nested data, like a folder structure or a list of items via category.

Comment: CMIIW, but if I do it that way, I will only get one giant model.  I won't be able to add, update or delete individual models in the collection, without writing my own custom code to do that.  If possible, I would like to do this all "The Backbone Way".

Comment: Then I'm misunderstanding the way your data is set up. Is it one model = two `<tr>`s? If so, you would have an `ItemView` representing one model, then assign the collection of models to a `CollectionView`.

Comment: No, you're correct. One model should be represented by two rows.  As far as I'm concerned, `CollectionView` or `CompositeView` are basically the same thing for the purposes of this discussion.  The problem is, if I have this stuff as one `ItemView`, Backbone will wrap it in a `<div>` and this is both illegal HTML and breaks the layout.  AFAIK, the only way to get the root element to not be a div is to specify _tagName_, with a value of 'tr' for example.  I tried this but Backbone will only output one `<tr>` element whereas I need two.  I will try to put together a jsFiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Why not try `<td>parent info here</td> <tr class="row-child"><td>child info here</td>` as your template and let `ItemView.tagName` take care of the first and last `<tr>`. This solution would be far less 'hackish' than either plan A or plan B.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well, refer to my original question.  Bottom line is, it doesn't work.

Comment: I see. I expected otherwise, as I'm sure you did. Set up a JSFiddle and I'll help from there.

Comment: Do you absolutely need two rows? Could you render something along these lines?: `<tr><td><div class="parent">...</div><div class="child">...</div></td></tr>`

Comment: @ChrisCamaratta, Yes I've considered that too and although there would be layout issues with columns lining up, that would be a possible workaround. But I think the original problem is still valid and I would like to figure out a solution for it, even if as nothing more than an intellectual exercise.  Actually, I can think of many situations where you would want to display multiple views for one model, so I think this would be a good extension for Marionette and I'm going to propose it to Derick Bailey.

Comment: why not alter the html?

Comment: @Blacksonic: Because **a)** that would be a way to avoid the problem, not solve it and while avoiding a problem is a perfectly valid response in the real world, this is a Q&A site to help solve problems, and **b)** the only sensible way to alter the html is to get rid of the table cells and replace them with divs.  At that point, I might as well get rid of tables altogether but tables are semantic.  They are the proper structure for displaying tabular data.  See my response to Chris Camaratta  above.

Comment: putting a table into a td element? that is semanticly good

Answer (score 4):

I struggled with that same problem until I finally discovered today, that a table can have multiple `tbody` tags, each one containing multiple `tr` tags.

This is actually [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7071268/3335922) provided to a similar backbone question.

So your `ItemView` would become:

```
var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template: ItemTmpl,
    tagName: 'tbody'
});
```

And the generated html:

```
<table>
  <!-- first item -->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-parent">
      <td>parent info here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-child">
      <td>child info here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- second item -->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-parent">
      <td>parent info here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-child">
      <td>child info here</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  ...
</table>
```

Comment: Actually, I should've updated my question but this is also the solution I came to.

Comment: This is elegant. Should probably be the accepted solution, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You could try modifying the CompositeView as follows:

1. Specify `itemView` as an array of views
2. Override `addChildView` to render each view for each model

This solution ends up looking a lot like your "Plan B". Give it a shot:

```
itemView: [My.ParentView, My.ChildView],

addChildView: function(item, collection, options){
  this.closeEmptyView();
  var itemViews = this.getItemView(item);
  var index = this.collection.indexOf(item);

  _.each(itemViews, function(ItemView) {
    this.addItemView(item, ItemView, index);
  });
}
```

I haven't thought through whether this would handle model events such as `destroy`, but I believe it should handle them gracefully.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer in the right direction.  I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @EML: For the most part, I get away with having one itemView, but I did have one scenario where each itemView had a sub-view.  It was a different implementation than above, though.  I'll see if I can put together a jsFiddle example for you.

Answer (score 0):

Dirty solution: Add a custom render function to your ItemView

```
// Or whatever template you use
var template = Handlebars.compile(datepickerTemplate);

var ItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    render: function(){
        var html = template(this.model.toJSON());
        var newElement = $(html);
        this.$el.replaceWith(newElement);
        this.setElement(newElement);
        return this;
    }
});
```

This should remove the extra div wrapping

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much **Plan A** and actually the solution I am using right now.  Except, I added the code to the `CompositeView`'s _appendHtml()_ method but it amounts to the same thing.
However, as I mentioned to Chris, I still think it's a valid, generalized problem and I'm interested in developing a more elegant and 'proper' longterm solution.  I think **Plan B** is that solution but I haven't had a chance to work on it yet.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm curious to know what this will do to the view's event binding. Please post your findings @TNguyen.