# How to create grouped table rows in Marionette 3

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have a collection of models which I have passed into Marionette to generate a HTML table, but every row of the table needs to be expandable with additional hidden details.

This is very much like this question aimed at the deprecated CompositeView: [How to show CompositeView with multiple children view in Backbone Marionette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18689150/how-to-show-compositeview-with-multiple-children-view-in-backbone-marionette)

The HTML structure that I'm trying to reproduce:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Qty</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <!-- first item -->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-parent">
      <td>1x</td>
      <td>Fruit Bowl</td>
      <td>£9.99</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-child">
      <td colspan="3">Some additional hidden info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <!-- second item -->
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-parent">
      <td>2x</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>£0.50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-child">
      <td colspan="3">Some additional hidden info</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

As each group can be an ItemView with a tagName of `tbody` the grouping isn't so much of the issue. It's the injecting the CollectionView into the table which I can't figure out.

I'm ending up with `tbody` inside the CollectionView's el. I'm not too sure how to get around that?

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/mzsgo3ay/5/